# Getting Session Closed. Spring+Jpa/Hibernate+Maven

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-orm

Hi everyone Am using Spring+Jpa/Hibernate+Maven and trying to get a record from DB. so when I rum my application am getting error like

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet] in context with path [/SpringHibernateMaven] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!] with root cause
>   org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
>       at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.errorIfClosed(AbstractSessionImpl.java:49)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1621)
>       at com.cdis.flod.dao.UserDao.getUserByName(UserDao.java:28)
>       at com.cdis.flod.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.getUserByName(UserServiceImpl.java:46)
>       at com.cdis.flod.web.LoginController.userLogin(LoginController.java:42)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

and here is the piece of code

```
public class AbstractDao<T> {

/** entity manager */
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "dbschema")
protected EntityManager entityManager;

public Session getHibernateSession() {
    return (Session) this.entityManager.getDelegate();
}



@Repository
```

public class UserDao extends AbstractDao{

```
public User getUserByName(String userName) {
    Query hqlQuery = getHibernateSession().createQuery("from User where userName=:name").
        setString(RequestParameters.name.name(), userName);

    return (User)hqlQuery.setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult();  
}
```

}

Comment: Is it a Web Application? Try using OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.

Comment: Hi Amir Pashazadeh :)

I have tried in this way and am able to get it..

**Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from User where user_name=:name", User.class);
  query.setParameter("name", userName);
  return (User) query.getSingleResult();**


But I din't understand what the mistake from my code.. 
appreciate you if u can help me with that :) 
Thanks :)

Comment: Thank You ver much Amir Pashazadeh 

I got it now by adding **OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter**

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The code bellow worked for me:

```
public class AbstractDao<T> {

/** entity manager */
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "dbschema")
protected EntityManager entityManager;

public Session getHibernateSession() {
    return ((Session) this.entityManager.getDelegate()).getSessionFactory().openSession();
}



@Repository
```